# illustrator pathfinder minus front not working?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

[image]

How come pathfinder - minus front is not working? I want a stylized N where that white part is taken out

[image]

Comment: In your image... the N is **not** selected... so nothing's going to happen.

Comment: I did select N when applying the effect..  not working still. what could be wrong?

Comment: What happens if you use the Pathfinder **Panel** rather than the effect?

Comment: @scott just added an image of what i think is a panel to the original posting. I think i was using panel already? ahh not sure what it's not working. is there any other way to achieve the effect?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the N is expanded, ungrouped with nothing funny going on in the appearance panel.
Same for the clipping shape.
Select both letter and clipping shape and use Divide from the pathfinder window.
Try the different pathfinder functions if that one doesn't do it.